# How to login to enable web query in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a website with certain data files saved behind a login/password. I have written a macro which gets the data and uses it but in order for it to work, the user needs to manually open a web query, go to my website and login with the 'remember me' box ticked.

I want to write some VBA code which does this automatically but can't figure out how. This is code I have to log in with Internet Explorer, and it works, but the web browser in the web query doesn't recognise its logged in, dont think it uses the same cookies or something

```
Sub IE_login()
Dim ie As Object
Dim C
Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
redo:
    MyLogin = Application.InputBox("Please enter your VBAX login", "VBAX username", Default:="login", Type:=2)
    MyPass = Application.InputBox("Please enter your VBAX password", "VBAX Password", Default:="Password", Type:=2)

If MyLogin = "" Or MyPass = "" Then GoTo redo

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://investingsidekick.com/wp-admin"

 'Look for password Form by finding test "Password"
For Each ieForm In ie.Document.forms
    If InStr(ieForm.innertext, "Password") <> 0 Then
        ULogin = True
         'enter details
        ieForm(0).Value = MyLogin
        ieForm(2).Value = MyPass
         'login
        ieForm.submit
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
If ULogin = False Then MsgBox "User is aleady logged in"
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the link ?

Comment: yes its http://investingsidekick.com/wp-admin

Comment: Also can you edit the question and put your code.

Comment: I've added some code I've used, which works for normal Internet explorer, but the web query doesn't recognise they've logged in

Comment: What is the data you wanna get ?

Answer (score 0):

This enters into login attempts loop to your site as anybody has your username/password then you (My Greetings!).

```
Function sofGetIELogin20018473()
'
  Dim i As Long, nMaxLogins As Long
  Dim ie As Object
  'Dim C
  Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
  Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String
'
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Navigate "http://investingsidekick.com/wp-admin"
  '
  nMaxLogins = 3
  ULogin = True
  '
  i = 0
  '
  ' enter into the loop of login attempts, maximum 3 attempts:
  '
  While (ULogin And i < nMaxLogins)
    '
    ' wait for the query response:
    '
    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
      DoEvents
    Loop
    '
    ' get username + password:
    '
    ie.Visible = False
    '
    MyLogin = InputBox("Please enter your VBAX login", "VBAX username", Default:="login")
    MyPass = InputBox("Please enter your VBAX password", "VBAX Password", Default:="Password")
    '
    ie.Visible = True

    '
    ' check username + password:
    '
    If MyLogin <> "" And MyPass <> "" Then

      '
      'Look for password Form by finding test "Password"
      '
      ULogin = False
      '
      For Each ieForm In ie.Document.Forms
        If InStr(ieForm.innertext, "Password") <> 0 Then
          ULogin = True
          'enter details
          ieForm.elements(0).Value = MyLogin
          ieForm.elements(1).Value = MyPass
          'login
          ieForm.submit
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
'
    End If
'
    i = i + 1
'
  Wend
'
  Set sofGetIELogin20018473 = ie
  Set ie = Nothing
'
  If (ULogin) Then
    MsgBox "User login failed."
  Else
    MsgBox "User is logged in."
  End If
'
End Function
```

And then you use this:

```
Sub sofIELogin20018473()
'
  Dim ie As Object
'
  Set ie = sofGetIELogin20018473()
  ie.Navigate "http://investingsidekick.com/my-secret-contents"
  '
  '...
  '
'
  Set ie = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that logs them in in Internet Explorer, but the problem is when I do a web query through Excel, it does not recognise they are logged in, as I dont think it share the same cookies or something.

Comment: You should use the same "ie" object with "login OK" that will send the good login cookie.

Comment: OK, I think I will have to get the data through the IE, then save it as a temporary file, then import that into excel. There doesn't appear to be any way to import data via a web query directly when it requires a log in.